# Ruby on Rails Validate date in jsonb (hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, jsonb

I have jsonb column in my Postgres db and i have a form with pref["date"] date_field for user.

How I can convert to date and validate user.pref["date"] that is date without error if convert to date will falls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rescue exception for invalid date conversion and add error then

```
begin
  date = Date.parse(pref['date'])
rescue ArgumentError
  # add error for invalid date
end
```